# How use values of list terraform variable in aws_policy.arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

main.tf

```
module "iam_assumable_role" {
  for_each     = var.service_accounts
  source       = "../../../../../../modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc/"
  create_role  = true
  role_name    = each.value.name
  provider_url = replace(module.eks.cluster_oidc_issuer_url, "https://", "")
  //  role_policy_arns              = [for i in each.value.policies : "aws_iam_policy.${i}.arn"]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects = each.value.wildcard == "" ? ["system:serviceaccount:${each.value.namespace}:${each.value.name}"] : []
  oidc_subjects_with_wildcards  = each.value.wildcard != "" ? ["system:serviceaccount:${each.value.namespace}:${each.value.wildcard}"] : []
  tags                          = var.tags
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "dev-policy1" {
  name_prefix = "dev-policy"
  description = "some description"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dev-policy1.json
}

variable "service_accounts" {
  type = map(object({
    name      = string
    namespace = string
    wildcard  = string
    policies  = list(any)
  }))
}
```

tfvars

```
 service_accounts                      = {
   "dev-sa" = {
      "name"                 = "dev-sa",
      "namespace"            = "dev",
      "wildcard"             = "*",
      "policies"             = ["dev-policy1", "dev-policy2"]
    },
   "qa-sa" = {
      "name"                 = "qa-sa",
      "namespace"            = "qa",
      "wildcard"             = "*",
      "policies"             = ["qa-policy1", "qa-policy2"]
    }
}
```

My code is iterating over service_accounts variable and creates appropriate resources. The problem is that in the commented line I cannot get the list of aws_iam_policy.arn s for the provided policy names (policy names are provided through service_account variable). My current code returns the aws_iam_policy.PolicyName.arn as string and not the actual value. Note that dev-policy1 resource s just one of the all policy resources. All policy documents exist as well. module itself is working correctly when I provide policy list directly and not through variable.

Is it possible to achieve the desired in terraform at all?

Comment: no luck yet, provided answer won't work either 'coz there are cases when the policies are the same. e.g. dev-sa has dev-policy1 and dev-policy2 policies and dev-sa2 has dev-policy1 and dev-policy3. Also ${i} don't work without quotes and when quotes are added tf understands it as list instead of real policy values.

Comment: Your question does not provide such a use-case where policies are same. The answer given is based on what you write in question, not on other hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: agree, my bad. but I still couldn't figure out how to achieve what I've described in question and above comment together.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `for_each`, to create your policies, as you can't dynamically references individual resources the way you are trying to do:

```
# get all policy names. Your names are unique, so its fine to use list
locals {
    policy_names = flatten(values(var.service_accounts)[*]["policies"])
}

# create policy for each name in `policy_names`
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  
  for_each = local.policy_names

  name_prefix = "dev-policy"
  description = "some description"

  # similar must be done below
  # policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dev-policy1.json
}
```

Then you refer to them as:

```
role_policy_arns              = [for i in each.value.policies: aws_iam_policy[${i}].arn]
```